Is it legal to scam pedophiles?
I am a minor. If I offer to sell explicit pictures to a pedophile, and then refuse to send said pictures after they pay me, would I get arrested?

Even if you don't get arrested, it doesn't mean you'll keep the money.

Don't do this. The person you are talking to may be a cop, running his own sting. And whatever parents are involved here will not take kindly to cops showing up on your door, asking questions.

“It’s a bad idea” doesn’t mean “it’s a bad question”. The scam victim will likely not call the police (but there have been cases where a drugs dealer called the police when someone stole his drugs, both arrested). But an angry pedophile could take illegal actions against you. Huge risk.

@gnasher729 they might not call the police but that doesn’t mean that they won’t retaliate.

@gnasher729 We usually find out about those in stories titled e.g. "Criminals are stupid".

It's impossible to answer "Would I get arrested?" It's better to ask "Could I get arrested?"

Except for varieties of self-defense, it's rarely legal to commit an offense against someone else just because they're committing an offense themselves. The law doesn't recognize "tit-for-tat" as an excuse.

Minors are generally free to void contracts, so there isn’t anything illegal about changing your mind about selling something to someone, even after you’ve been paid, though you are likely obligated to return the funds you've accepted.
It is not necessarily illegal to "scam pedophiles," but there are plenty of scams that are illegal, regardless of who the target is.
For instance, offering to sell child pornography is a federal felony, regardless of whether you complete the transaction or not. 18 U.S. Code § 2252A(a)(6).
Are you likely to be arrested, charged, convicted, and imprisoned as a result of this gag? I’d guess not, but that’s your own risk to assess.

Just because they are a minor doesn’t mean that they won’t be charged. https://www.gelmanlawfirm.com/blog/is-it-possible-that-my-child-will-be-charged-with-a-crime-if-caught-sexting/#

Assuming the OP doesn't really have child pornography, (A)(3)(b) probably better applies. (A)(6) requires one to actually own such content.

@JoeW I don't think anyone is suggesting otherwise.

@PMF I don't I think that's correct. It's enough if the offer is transmitted online or over the phone.

That is what I am reading from your answer, if this gets on the police/legal systems radar they would have both fraud and child porn charges and both of them tend to go well with voters.

The answer actually says the opposite. It notes the potential criminal charges and the risk of being charged. In any event, I think I'd disagree that police would be excited about a headline like, "Police charge teen girl with felony for catching child pornographer."

There was that show to catch a predator that offered kiddy literature to predators in a sting operation
